# how do i process multiple files with an existing python script

Tags: python

i have >100 .cwa files (raw accelerometery data) and have a .py programme which processes the .cwa data and produces a .csv file.  How do i write a script in python which can process all the .cwa files with my .py without having to individually insert the filename into the command line.

i am new to programming, i have looked at glob.glob and os. walk but don't understand how to use these process multiple files.  i want to read in 1 x .cwa file at a time, process it using my .py and then move onto the next .cwa until all have been read and there are the corresponding number of csv files as an output.  i do not want to merge the data into one file.

Comment: `glob` and `os.walk` are good tools for a single directory or whole subtree search. I suggest you learn those tools. Searching "python glob" and "python os.walk" gives lots of examples and tutorials. You could put `[python] glob` in the search bar here on stackoverflow and get lots of good hits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell scripting (here is a bash example for Linux) to list files in a directory and call a command for each file:

```sh
find /path/to/cwa/files/ -type f -name "*.cwa" -exec /path/to/script.py {} \;
```

This example assumes that script.py takes a single argument which is a CWA filepath, e.g. `script.py /my/cwa/file.cwa`

If you want to stick with Python, a for-loop with `os.listdir` might be the easiest approach. Let's assume that your CWA-processing code is in the `process_cwa()` function:

```py
import os

CWA_DIR = '/path/to/cwa/files'

def process_cwa(path):
    # process CWA file
    pass

# process CWA files from CWA_DIR on disk
for file in os.listdir(CWA_DIR):
    if file.endswith(".cwa"):
        path = os.path.join(CWA_DIR, file)
        process_cwa(path)
```

Comment: thankyou - the processing cwa code is however in a .py file rather than a function, so I would need to call the .py.

Comment: By the time OP figures out `find` on linux or equivalent on Windows, s/he might as well have figured out `glob` or `os.walk`.